# Given random variables X and Z, can I (symmetrically) constuct a Y such that X, Y, Z is a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, information-theory

The following problem is giving me a bit of a headache:

Let $X, Z$ be a pair of random variables.
Under which conditions can I construct a random variable $Y$ such that
$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow  Z$ is a Markov chain? In order to avoid trivial solutions such as $X=Y$ I additionally require the construction to be symmetrical with respect to $X$ and $Z$.
That is, if I change $X$ and $Z$ when defining $Y$, I obtain the same random variable.

I am thinking of $Y$ of some sort of variable that captures the common "information" between $X$ and $Z$. Maybe it even holds that $I(X, Y) = I(Y, Z)$?

So far I have not even been able to find such $Y$ under the assumption that $X$ and $Z
$ to be correlated standard normal distributions (using the standard Brownian process did not work). Hence any answer under any assumption is very welcome :)

When I say that the construction of $Y$ should be symmetrical I mean that the following.
Let $\Omega$ be the space on which the variables $X, Y, Z$ are defined and let us denote by $\gamma*f$ the push forward of $\gamma$ through a function $f$. Then we are looking for a map $\pi$ that associates a joint probability distribution $\gamma$ on $\Omega^2$ to a probability distribution $\pi(\gamma)$ on $\Omega^3$.
This map must satisfy the following requirements:

- (Marginal condition) For all joint probability distributions $\gamma$ it must hold that:
  $\pi(\gamma)_*p_{1,3} = \gamma$ $ \text{where} \ p_{1,3}(x, y, z)
     = x, z$
- (Symmetry condition) $\pi(\gamma)=\pi(\gamma_*f) \quad \text{where} \ f(x, z) = z, x$
- (Markov condition) $(X, Y, Z)\sim \pi(\gamma)$ imples that $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain.

Edit: After discussing this question in the comments I realized that such a $\pi$ is easy to construct if we create some decision rule that sets $Y=X$ of $Y=Z$ based on some symmetric condition on $X, Z$..

Comment: You might need more conditions if you want to rule out a $Y$ that just encodes the pair $(X,Z)$, like (if all r.v.s are real) the number obtained by interleaving the binary digits of $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: I really did not think of that.. But how would you "symmetrically" encode $X$ and $Z$? I mean, wouldn't in general an encoding of $(X, Z)$ be different from $(Z, X)$?

Comment: Oh, good point. I'm starting to doubt that such a $Y$ always exists. My informal reasoning is: in a general case, the conditional distributions $P(Z|X=x)$ for different values of $x$ are unrelated to each other, so if $Z$ is independent of $X$ given $Y$, it seems like we must actually be able to recover $X$ from $Y$. But if $X=f(Y)$, then by your symmetry condition, $Z=f(Y)$, so $X=Z$. So I suspect the "splitting" is only possible under stronger conditions on the joint distribution of $X,Z$.

Comment: Uhm, you are right. If $Z=f(X)$ and $f$ is injective then by your reasoning nothing else can be done but choosing (up to bijection) $Y=X$ or $Y=Z$. 
In any case I tried to formalize the symmetry condition and am now convinced that my question is not that interesting anymore.. Thanks for answering though :)